# Web3Modal with WalletConnect not opening on mobile

Tags: walletconnect

I am using Web3Modal with WalletConnect and Web3Button within a Nextjs 13 application. Wallet connection works fine on desktop, but on mobile the Web3Modal won't even appear, and the Web3Button just displays a loading icon.

Here is how I am configuring the Web3 stuff:

```js
"use client";

import { configureChains } from "wagmi";
import { w3mProvider } from "@web3modal/ethereum";
import { createClient } from "wagmi";

import { EthereumClient, w3mConnectors } from "@web3modal/ethereum";
import { arbitrum, mainnet, polygon } from "wagmi/chains";

const chains = [arbitrum, mainnet, polygon];

export { Web3Modal } from "@web3modal/react";
export { WagmiConfig } from "wagmi";

export const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YOUR_PROJECT_ID as string;

export const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [
  w3mProvider({ projectId }),
]);

export const wagmiClient = createClient({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, version: 1, chains }),
  provider,
});

export const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiClient, chains);
```

And here is how I am adding Web3Modal to the layout.tsx file:

```
<Web3Modal
     projectId={projectId}
     explorerExcludedWalletIds={"ALL"}
     explorerRecommendedWalletIds={[
          process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_METAMASK_WALLET_ID as string,
          process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COINBASE_WALLET_ID as string,
     ]}
     ethereumClient={ethereumClient}
/>
```

Any ideas what may be going wrong to cause this?

Comment: Do you have error logs, in either your terminal or the developer console in Browser ?